# clang++ - Fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found

Tags: clang

I'm using clang 2.9, compiled from source and when I try to compile a simple code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (){
  std::cout << "Hello\n";
}
```

I get the error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.5/string:39:10: fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found
```

When I include `/usr/include/c++/4.5/i686-linux-gnu`, I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this one?

Comment: Try trunk clang; and if that doesn't work, file a bug in LLVM Bugzilla, and include what OS (which Linux distro, if applicable) you're using.

Comment: I have the same issue with clang 3.4 (compiled from trunk) on Ubuntu.